# tags implementation in angular and node

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to implement tags like the one there is here when posting a question.
I'm using html, angular and node.js

I would like each time a user writes a tag that it will look in the database in order to see if the tag exist and if not, to let him write a new tag anyway.

**on the client side**

so this is my input in my html file

```
 <label for="pwd">Tags:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" ng-model="Tags" name="Tags[]">
```

this is what is written in my controller

```
mymedical.controller('insertPersonalCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.createPersonalData = function(){     
                var data = {};      
                data.email = $scope.email;
                data.Tags[] = $scope.Tags[];
                data.title = $scope.title;
                data.Info = $scope.Info;
                data.Category = $scope.Category;
                data.file = $scope.file;
                data.Recommendation = $scope.Recommendation;      
        }
}]);
```

but i need it to insert all the words as an array of string and now it is only one string...
I need to word to be separated by the key space ' '

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more Javascript than AngularJS.

All you have to do is to [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the tags `string` coming your `<input type="text"`

`data.tags.split(' ')` then query each one on the API (either on input change or on form submit), just like you do with your other calls.

```
data.tags.split(' ').forEach((tag) => {
  // Do something.
});
```